# Feature request: vote again on the same answer/question in time

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

When a question/answer is extremely helpful I think it would be a good idea to be able to vote on it again after some time.

Say something like 6 months or so, if you come across the same question (and answer) again and think it might deserve another upvote, that you can help the question/answer user again.

Maybe it would be a good idea to have this functionality as of a certain amount of reputation.

Comment: A vote is to indicate "usefulness" which is a binary state...it either is or isn't. Voting more than once doesn't make it "more useful".

Comment: May I downvote this feature request twice?

Comment: @Paulie_D: how is usefulness a binary state? Just to name one example: a same answer can be useful in different situations...

Comment: ..but we're not talking about other situations. We're talking about a single answer to a single question. Either it's useful or it's not. Period.

Comment: SO already has issues with voting rings already. This would escalate the issue with no real benefit.

Comment: *Maybe it would be a good idea to have this functionality as of a certain amount of reputation.* I'm not convinced that letting some user's opinions on whether a post is useful matter more than others is a good idea. Many people don't even like letting the question author's opinion on an answer's usefulness carry more weight than anyone else.

Comment: "Helping" a user by voting is already entirely the wrong reason to vote.

Comment: @Gimby: ok, I'm listening ;) what is the good reason to vote?

Comment: @Bamboomy When the question or answer you are voting for is particularly useful or good.

Comment: @Bamboomy content quality. Nothing more.

Comment: Well..... Jon Skeet will be at 2 million tomorrow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As was already pointed out by others, votes do not expire. So there is no need to add them again.

However... some answers *are* more useful than others. If you find an answer very useful, you can set a bounty on the question and award it to that specific answer. There is a specific bounty reason for that:

> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

And you can do that multiple times, too - it'll cost you rep, but you can do it as long as you have enough rep to award bounties.

Comment: Let's wait 6 months to be accepted twice.

Answer (score 9):

Let's not.

These votes do not expire, time passing doesn't devalue an existing vote.
Why should a user be rewarded even more for nothing doing *anything* with an existing answer?

What's to stop anyone from writing a script upvoting all answers they upvoted in the past, regularly?

This will only lead to increased rep rewards without any exta work done to warrant the extra reward.

Comment: "What's to stop anyone from writing a script upvoting all answers they upvoted in the past, regularly?" The 40 vote per day limit, mostly.  (Only 30 of which can be on answers.)

Comment: @Servy: well played. But it'd be one way to make sure you spend those 40 votes on a daily basis.